# In Qiskit, where is the floating point operation performed?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I am using Qiskit  - the simple circuits I am writing can either run on the hardware backend (using least_busy) or the QASM simulator backend.

If I have statements like the following - (`random_numbers` were generated using QRNG in the circuits - not shown here)

```
b = .6
a = .3
flt = []

for rn_num in random_numbers:
     flt.append( b*(a-rn_num) + a * rn_num)
```

Where are these floating point operations performed? I am connected to IBM Quantum Experience - using Jupyter. Are these operations performed on a traditional machine or a quantum backend?

My understanding is unless it is related to a Quantum circuit - everything gets executed on a traditional machine (similar to print or sockets?)

Is there a document that explains this further? I read release notes - I found them a bit ambiguous. I found this comment in **Aer 0.3** release note

> Increased performance with simulations that require less floating
>   point numerical precision.

Maybe this note is referring to statevectors in floating point ...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qiskit backends (quantum devices or simulators) work only when you explicitly invoke them, usually with `execute`. The code in your snippet does not call `qiskit`, and runs on a traditional machine.